# Why does GraphQL require me to have a resolver that returns an empty object?

Tags: graphql

So, when I have a schema:

```
type Query { me: Me } 
type Me { hello: String }
```

I expect a satisfying resolver to be:

```js
const resolvers = {
  Me: {
     hello() { return "Hi, me!"; }
  }
}
```

Alas, this isn't the case, I have to add a dummy `me`-resolver (see below).

Why is this the case?

I'd say it should traverse the query, and if it can't find a satisfying `field`-resolver, it should look for a corresponding `type`-resolver.

```js
const { graphql } = require("graphql");
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require("graphql-tools");
const compose = require("compose-function");

const typeDefs = `
  type Query {
    me: Me
  }

  type Me {
    hello: String!
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
// ===========================>
    me() {
      return {};
    }
// <===========================
  },
  Me: {
    hello() {
      return "Hi, me!";
    }
  }
};

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});

graphql(schema, "{ me { hello } }").then(
  compose(
    console.log,
    JSON.stringify
  )
); // {"data":{"me":{"hello":"Hi, me!"}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I've figured it out. It actually makes a lot of sense.

`null` is a valid response. Only if there is an object with properties that the query wants, it should look for the next resolver to satisfy the query.

It's also written in the spec under **Errors and Non‐Null Fields** https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Executing-Selection-Sets